# Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not private array) near "@array)"

Tags: arrays, perl

Get following error while attempting to run below code.

Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not private array) near "@array)"

The idea of the code is compare two arrays data.  This method works on my home server, but will not work on the server it needs implemented on.

Not sure where to go with it.

```
 foreach (sort keys @array){
        unless (exists $group_list[$_]){
            print "$_: not found\n";
            next;
        }
        if (equivalent($array[$_],$group_list[$_])){
            print "$_: values are equal\n"
        }else{
            print "$_: values are not equal\n";
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: `keys` is only defined when used on a hash in Perl. What are you trying to accomplish here? Just sort the array by value ?

Comment: `@array` is an array, and `sort keys` is to go through the keys of a hash. Is `group_list` also an array? You can use `for my $i (0 .. $#Array) { }` to go through an array while storing the index in `$i`.

Comment: I am trying to compare two array's data to each other.  The method worked on my home server, but not the server it needs implemented on.

Comment: The server is running 5.10.1.  Is there any way around it, aside from updating the perl version?

Answer (score 3):

`keys @array` only works on newer perls, and should therefore generally be avoided. We can write down the range of indices directly without much extra syntax: Unless `$[` has been set, indices start with `0` and are a continuous range up to `$#array`, the last index. Then:

```
for (sort 0 .. $#array)
```

Note that this range is already sorted numerically, and `sort` will sort it alphabetically. Remove the `sort` if that behavior is not desired:

```
for (0 .. $#array)
```

That is the normal idiom for iterating over all indices.

Note also that (unless you do highly unusual things), `exists $array[$_]` will probably be true, so this test is not likely to be useful (it can be false e.g. if you preextended the array to a specific size: `$#array = $size - 1`). Testing whether an entry is `defined` is more likely to be useful.